# List Manipulation with references

Tags: java, list

So for my assignment we are to implement some referenced based list manipulation methods in a class and then add to a list and demonstrate the methods using a driver file.

I have provided the entire program for download which includes a `pdf` that explains the assignment. Our professor uploaded a completed driver file and mine is exactly the same as his but I am getting some run-time errors, first is when calling `add()` for the third time I get a `NullPointerException`, if I comment out the rest of the `add()` calls, `size()` will not return the same size as `getSize()` and `getSizeRecursive().`

Please Help me. Link to download: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qe771q3156h9nwx/ListReferenceBased.rar

```
// ****************************************************
// Reference-based implementation of ADT list.
// ****************************************************
public class ListReferenceBased implements ListInterface {
// reference to linked list of items
private Node head;
private int numItems; // number of items in list

public ListReferenceBased() {
    numItems = 0;
    head = null;
}  // end default constructor

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return numItems == 0;
}  // end isEmpty

public int size() {
    return numItems;
}  // end size

private Node find(int index) {
    // --------------------------------------------------
    // Locates a specified node in a linked list.
    // Precondition: index is the array index of the desired node.
    // Assumes that 0 <= index < numItems
    // Postcondition: Returns a reference to the desired node.
    // --------------------------------------------------
    Node curr = head;
    for (int skip = 0; skip < index; skip++) {
        curr = curr.getNext();
    } // end for
    return curr;
} // end find

public Object get(int index)
throws ListIndexOutOfBoundsException {
    if (index >= 0 && index < numItems) {
        // get reference to node, then data in node
        Node curr = find(index);
        Object dataItem = curr.getItem();
        return dataItem;
    }
    else {
        throw new ListIndexOutOfBoundsException(
        "List index out of bounds on get");
    } // end if
} // end get

public void add(int index, Object item)
throws ListIndexOutOfBoundsException {
    if (index >= 0 && index <= numItems) {
        if (index == 0) {
            // insert the new node containing item at
            // beginning of list
            Node newNode = new Node(item, head);
            head = newNode;
        }
        else {
            Node prev = find(index-1);
            // insert the new node containing item after
            // the node that prev references
            Node newNode = new Node(item, prev.getNext());
            prev.setNext(newNode);
        } // end if
        numItems++;
    }
    else {
        throw new ListIndexOutOfBoundsException(
        "List index out of bounds on add");
    } // end if
}  // end add

public void remove(int index)
throws ListIndexOutOfBoundsException {
    if (index >= 0 && index < numItems) {
        if (index == 0) {
            // delete the first node from the list
            head = head.getNext();
        }
        else {
            Node prev = find(index-1);
            // delete the node after the node that prev
            // references, save reference to node
            Node curr = prev.getNext();
            prev.setNext(curr.getNext());
        } // end if
        numItems--;
    } // end if
    else {
        throw new ListIndexOutOfBoundsException(
        "List index out of bounds on remove");
    } // end if
}   // end remove

public void removeAll() {
    // setting head to null causes list to be
    // unreachable and thus marked for garbage
    // collection
    head = null;
    numItems = 0;
} // end removeAll


// TO IMPLEMENT
public String toString(){
    Node curr = head;
    String str = new String("");
    while(curr != null){
        str += curr.getItem() + ", ";
        curr = curr.getNext();
    }
    return str;
}


// TO IMPLEMENT
public void reverse(){
    Node prev = null;
    Node curr = head;
    while(curr != null){
        Node next = curr.getNext();
        curr.setNext(prev);
        prev = curr;
        curr = next;
    }
    head = prev;
}


// TO IMPLEMENT
// This is a helper method, so try to define your own method
// that this helper will call.
public void reverseRecursive(){
    Node prev = null;
    Node curr = head;
    reverseRecursiveHelper(prev, curr);
    head = prev;
}
public Object reverseRecursiveHelper(Node prev, Node curr){
    if(curr == null)
    return null;
    else {
        Node next = curr.getNext();
        curr.setNext(prev);
        prev = curr;
        curr = next;
        return reverseRecursiveHelper(prev, curr);
    }
}


// TO IMPLEMENT
public int getSize()
// --------------------------------------------------
// Returns the number of items in a linked list.
// Precondition: head points to the first element
// in a list of type node.
// Postcondition: The number of items in the list
// is returned.
// --------------------------------------------------
{
    int count = 0;
    Node curr = head;
    while(curr != null){
        curr = curr.getNext();
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}


// TO IMPLEMENT
public int getSize(Node cur)
// --------------------------------------------------
// Returns the number of items in a linked list.
// The initial call should have the beginning of the list
// as it's input argument, i.e. listCount(head);
// Precondition: cur points to a list of type node
// Postcondition: The number of items in the list
// is returned.
// --------------------------------------------------
{
    if(cur != null)
    return 1 + getSize(cur.getNext());
    else //base case
        return 0;

}


// TO IMPLEMENT
public int getSizeRecursive()
{
    return getSize(head);
}


// TO IMPLEMENT
public Node findMToLast(int m){
    Node current = head;
    if(current == null)
    return null;
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    if(current.getNext() != null)
    current = current.getNext();
    else
        return null;
    Node mBehind = head;
    while (current.getNext() != null){
        current = current.getNext();
        mBehind = mBehind.getNext();
    }
    return mBehind;
}


} // end ListReferenceBased
```

Driver:

```
// ********************************************************
// Test Reference-based implementation of the ADT list.
// *********************************************************
public class TestListReferenceBased {



static public void main(String[] args)
{
    ListReferenceBased aList = new ListReferenceBased();

    aList.add(0, new Integer(1));
    aList.add(1, new Integer(2));
    aList.add(2, new Integer(3));
    aList.add(3, new Integer(4));
    aList.add(4, new Integer(5));
    aList.add(5, new Integer(6));

    System.out.println("size() and get(i): ");
    for (int i = 0; i < aList.size(); i++)
        System.out.println(aList.get(i) + " ");
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Size with size() = " + aList.size());
    System.out.println("Size with getSize() = " + aList.getSize());
    System.out.println("Size with getSizeRecursive() = " + aList.getSizeRecursive());

    System.out.println("Initial List = " + aList);
    aList.reverse();    // iterative version
    System.out.println("Reverse with reverse() = " + aList);

    System.out.println("====================================");

    aList.reverseRecursive();   // recursive version
    System.out.println("Reverse with reverseRecursive() = " + aList);

        int offset = 3;
    Node node = aList.findMToLast(offset);
    if (node != null)
        System.out.println(offset + "-th node to the last node contains " +  node.getItem() + ".");
    else
        System.out.println("Offset(=" + offset + ") to the last node is greater than list size(=" + aList.size() + ").");

} // end main

}  // end TestListReferenceBased
```

Stack trace is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at
    ListReferenceBased.add(ListReferenceBased.java:63) at
    TestListReferenceBased.main(TestListReferenceBased.java:14)
```

Comment: As stated in your original version of this question: Please post your stack traces, and clearly identify the corresponding lines in the code snippets.

Comment: I tried but if I edit anything it says my code is not formatted right, even though it is and previews fine, and it won't let me save changes. Stack Trace is:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at ListReferenceBased.add(ListReferenceBased.java:63)
        at TestListReferenceBased.main(TestListReferenceBased.java:14)

Comment: Next, clearly identify the corresponding lines in the code snippets. What line is *ListReferenceBased.java:63*?

Comment: It is in add(int index, Object item). The line is Node newNode = new Node(item, prev.getNext());

Comment: TestListReferenceBased.java:14 is in the driver file. it is the line: aList.add(2, new Integer(3));

Comment: Then `prev` is `null`, which implies that `find(index-1)` returned `null`. Try adding some temporary print-outs to `find` to make sure it is behaving as expected?

Comment: I decided to check the other files included in the program and it turned out that my professor had set everything in Node Class to pinpoint null. After I fixed Node Class everything worked as expected.